# skipping elements with Map() and match() in R

Tags: r

I'd like to recode the values in the `df1` data frame using the `df2` data frame so that I end up with a data frame like `df3`.

The current code almost does the trick, but there are two problems. First, it introduces `NA` when there's no match, e.g. there is no match in `df2` for the `df1` `aed_bloodpr` variable value `"1,2"` so the value becomes `NA`. Second, when a variable in `df1` can't be mapped to `df2`, the code won't run (error message).

Have looked into the `nomatch` argument for `match()` and the .default argument for `Map()`, but I can't figure out how to use them so that I end up with `df3`.

Starting point:

```
Df1 <- data.frame("aed_bloodpr" = c("1,2","2","1","1"),
                  "aed_gluco" = c("2","1","3","2"),
                  "add_bmi" = c("2","5,7","7","5"),
                  "add_asthma" = c("2","2","7","5"),
                  "nausea" = c("3","3","4","5"))

Df2 <- data.frame("NameOfVariable" = c("aed_bloodpr","aed_bloodpr","aed_gluco","aed_gluco","aed_gluco","add_bmi","add_bmi","add_bmi"),
                  "VariableLevel" = c(1,2,1,2,3,2,5,7),
                  "VariableDef" = c("high","normal","elevated","normal","NA","above","normal","below"))
```

End point:

```
Df3 <- data.frame("aed_bloodpr" = c("1,2","normal","high","high"),
                  "aed_gluco" = c("normal","elevated","NA","normal"), 
                  "add_bmi" = c("above","5,7","below","normal"), 
                  "add_asthma"=c("2","2","7","5"), 
                  "nausea" = c("3","3","4","5"))
```

Current code:

```
data.frame(Map(function(x, y) y[[2]][match(x, y[[1]])],
           Df1,
           split(Df2[2:3], Df2[1])[names(Df1)]))
```

Comment: Firstly, store numbers as numbers (and `NA` as `NA`), not strings. It's particularly problematic when you pass them to `data.frame` without `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, because strings will get turned into factors, which internally are stored as different numbers, which can cause a lot of confusion if you call `as.numeric` or similar on them.

Comment: Are the quoted numbers within `Df1` intended to be categorical and not ordinal/integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean up before you can relabel. The actual relabeling is more easily accomplished by a join. Here using the tidyverse (translate as you like):

```r
library(tidyverse)

Df1 <- data.frame("aed_bloodpr" = c("1,2","2","1","1"),
                  "aed_gluco" = c("2","1","3","2"),
                  "add_bmi" = c("2","5,7","7","5"),
                  "add_asthma" = c("2","2","7","5"),
                  "nausea" = c("3","3","4","5"))

Df2 <- data.frame("NameOfVariable" = c("aed_bloodpr","aed_bloodpr","aed_gluco","aed_gluco","aed_gluco","add_bmi","add_bmi","add_bmi"),
                  "VariableLevel" = c(1,2,1,2,3,2,5,7),
                  "VariableDef" = c("high","normal","elevated","normal","NA","above","normal","below"))

Df1_long <- Df1 %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>%    # change factors to strings
    rowid_to_column('i') %>%    # add row index to enable later long-to-wide reshape
    gather(variable, value, -i) %>%    # reshape to long form
    separate_rows(value, convert = TRUE)    # unnest nested values and convert to numeric

str(Df1_long)
#> 'data.frame':    22 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ i       : int  1 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 ...
#>  $ variable: chr  "aed_bloodpr" "aed_bloodpr" "aed_bloodpr" "aed_bloodpr" ...
#>  $ value   : int  1 2 2 1 1 2 1 3 2 2 ...

Df2_clean <- Df2 %>% 
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%    # change factors to strings
    mutate_all(na_if, 'NA')    # change "NA" to NA

Df3 <- Df1_long %>% 
    left_join(Df2_clean, by = c('variable' = 'NameOfVariable',    # merge
                                'value' = 'VariableLevel')) %>% 
    mutate(VariableDef = coalesce(VariableDef, as.character(value))) %>%    # combine labels and values
    group_by(i, variable) %>% 
    summarise(value = toString(VariableDef)) %>%    # re-aggregate multiple values
    spread(variable, value)    # reshape to wide form

Df3
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Groups:   i [4]
#>       i add_asthma       add_bmi  aed_bloodpr aed_gluco nausea
#> * <int>      <chr>         <chr>        <chr>     <chr>  <chr>
#> 1     1          2         above high, normal    normal      3
#> 2     2          2 normal, below       normal  elevated      3
#> 3     3          7         below         high         3      4
#> 4     4          5        normal         high    normal      5
```

Comment: I get "Error: Additional arguments should be named" when trying to run Df2_clean <-...

Comment: Is your dplyr up-to-date? You shouldn't need to specify names, though you can: `mutate_all(na_if, y = 'NA')` or you can use `funs` syntax: mutate_all(funs(na_if(., 'NA'))) or since the rlang changeover, purrr-style syntax: `mutate_all(~na_if(.x, 'NA'))` or base R syntax: `mutate_all(function(vec){na_if(vec, 'NA')})`